# how to use node.attribute to check if node attribute exist or not?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

want to check if chef attribute is declared or not in recipe,
but it seems not working as expected,
can anyone tell me how i can do it properly using "node.attribute?"

here is scenario
there are attribute that might not be declared while chef-client is executed as this parameter is optional and might be passing in chef-client -j some.json file as externally

```
if node.attribute(node['some']['attr'])
   list = node['some']['attr']
else
   list = node['defalut_attr']
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby we can use `nil` to indicate something as empty. For your purpose, you can use this functionality to initially keep your node attribute as empty. Then provide a value externally if required.

**Example:**

In your `attributes/default.rb`:

```ruby
default['some']['attr'] = nil
default['default_attr'] = 'one, two, three, four'
```

In a `some.json`:

```json
{
    "some": {
        "attr": "one, two"
    }
}
```

Then in your `recipes/default.rb`:

```ruby
list = nil

if node['some']['attr'].nil?
  list = node['default_attr']
else
  list = node['some']['attr']
end

puts "***** list: #{list}"
```

Now if you set the value through `-j some.json`, *that* value will be used for `list`. Otherwise `list` will be set to `node['default_attr']`.

**Update**:

When you supplied the `-j some.json` for the first time, the [node attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes/) were saved. So in next run `['some']['attr']` was not `nil` anymore. To make this work:

1. You will have to `edit node` and delete this attribute.
2. Run chef-client in `--override-runlist` mode (and skip node save).

Example:

Without `some.json`:

```
~$ chef-client -o recipe[my_cookbook]

Compiling Cookbooks...

***** list: one, two, three, four
```

With `some.json`:

```
~$ chef-client -o recipe[my_cookbook] -j ./node.json

Compiling Cookbooks...

***** list: one, two
```

**Note**: While this will solve this particular requirement, skipping node save always is not a good idea. You might want to rethink on making use of attribute precedence to work for your use case.

Comment: some.json file contains "some":{ "attr":"one,two"}  , however by "default_attr" = "one,two, three, fouur,five",   wihtout running chef-client with some.json, it should take default_attr , but in run result it is taking ['some']['attr']

Comment: Is the `default_attr` also defined in `some.json`? I think you should declare `default['default_attr']` in `attributes/default.rb`.

Comment: yes it is declred in both external json as well as internal attribute default file

Comment: The attributes specified from `some.json` may be getting saved on node when chef-client completes. I will update my answer.

Comment: dont know what was exact problem , but it start working today morning , without even declaring nil attribute in default attribute file.

Answer (score 0):

The `node.exist?()` helper is designed for it:

```
list = if node.exist?("some", "attr")
         node['some']['attr']
       else
         node['default_attr']
       end
```

There are also other helpers which make life easier:

```
# this avoids "trainwrecking" with NoMethodError on NilClass if node["some"] does not exist
# and will return nil if the attribute is not found.
#
list = node.read("some", "attr")

# there is also an alias to #dig which was created after Hash#dig was added to ruby:
#
list = node.dig("some", "attr")

# this raises a consistent Chef::AttributeNotFound error if the attribute does not exist:
#
list = node.read!("some", "attr")
```

Also if you really need to you can use all those methods on the sub-Mashes (default/override/etc):

```
# this only checks the default level:
node.default.exist?("some", "attr")
```

You probably want to consider if your code knows too much too deeply about how it is being used though if you're poking around in the individual precedence levels like that.  I would heavily discourage use of that API other than for debugging purposes.